# Are questions asking about game files on topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Are questions like these,

- [What does each option in game.cfg mean?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/308512/what-does-each-option-in-game-cfg-mean)
- [Where and in what format are the in-game assets, sounds, models, etc. stored?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/286282/where-and-in-what-format-are-the-in-game-assets-sounds-models-etc-stored)

Asking about the games files and such on topic? Looking at the help center, they don't appear to be on topic but they don't appear to be explicitly off-topic either.

I've been looking around the unanswered questions and finding a moderate amount of questions like this and was just curious if there was something to be done with them because I feel like they're either not well suited to be answered here or can't necessarily be answered.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Questions like these are on topic, with exceptions.

Usually, questions like this are asking about config files (like your first example) or about asset/resource files (like your second example). These are okay if the question is asking where the files are located or (in the case of the config file) what the available settings mean. However, we draw the line at questions that are more developer-oriented. For example, asking why a particular file format was chosen, or how to modify the asset files to create a mod, or how to decode a file, are all off-topic.