# Are bug workaround questions which involve editing game files a good fit?

Tags: discussion

**Context**: [Why can't I make the HRE elective?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/332220/why-cant-i-make-the-hre-elective)

Ivan's useful answer suggests [creating a minimod to work around the issue](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/332426/147843):

> If you're not playing Ironman, you could edit this file by creating a minimod fixing the issue.

I would quite like to do this to verify the answer is correct - admittedly it looks strongly like this is the case - so that I can both accept it and actually resolve the issue.

However, it seems not to be as simple as just editing the file itself because of how the defines in the files are resolved between core and mods. So I figured I would ask a question which would be useful for future querants.

Before I do so, I wanted to check that such a thing would be on-topic (think so!), and a good fit (???) for Arquade. I do note that mod development is off topic:

> Please note, however, that site policies prohibit questions of the following types:
>
> - Game and Mod Development (try the Game Development Stack Exchange instead)

But this isn't really about mod *development* as such.

**Shall I go ahead and ask ask?**

### References

- [Are questions asking about game files on topic?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12915/are-questions-asking-about-game-files-on-topic)

A grue ate some of the URLs I had when I was going to ask this before, but I'll see if I can find the meta topic I read.

Comment: If the question is about an issue in the game, and modifying the game files is one way to alleviate the issue, that doesn't mean the question is not valid.

Comment: @FoxMcCloud That's what I figured. I [posted a question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/333507/how-do-i-get-changes-to-faction-criteria-to-take-effect-so-i-can-create-an-elec) and feedback would be welcome; and/or converting that comment to an answer ! :)

Comment: I think that's a valid question based on an in-game bug and requiring a work-around to get it working. Question seems valid and well thought out. Looks good to me.

Comment: @FoxMcCloud thanks for the feedback :)

Answer (score -3):

**To be clear**: as stated in the first sentence, this response concerns OP's *[follow-up question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/333507/)* which they linked in the comments, and *not* the post linked in the question body.

---

I personally don't believe the follow-up question is on-topic. Modding is modding, whether for new functionality, or to fix a bug. (Or in this case, it appears, for a little bit of A and a little bit of B.)

Specifically, asking questions on how to solve a problem is fine, but if the problem could only possibly come up because of interference by a mod, then it's not a valid question to be solved here. The primary thing to ask yourself when asking a question is: could a gamer solve this problem without having arcane knowledge in a non-gaming topic? Here, I think you'd need to be unusually intimate with CK2 modding to solve the problem. And [we've determined in the past](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/562/) that modding is programming, not gaming.

I think a preferable option is to ask for additional help in the comments of the answer you were given, or better yet, in a (StackExchange) chatroom. You could then leave a comment pointing to the transcript, and edit the answer to reflect the final changes. And, if you felt so inclined, award a bounty to the answerer for their detailed assistance.

Comment: An interesting point of view! Although I wonder if that could also be applied to the linked 'game files' question too? I don't want to add any functionality to the game; and it is solely due to a Paradox bug in the base game- not interference from another mod/mods. Perhaps I could edit the [main site] question to make that part clearer?

Comment: Downvoter: I'd appreciate a comment explaining what you disagree with, please. :)

Comment: could a gamer solve this problem without having obscure, expert knowledge in another topic - I disagree with this premise of your answer. I also disagree with saying "modding is modding", because I don't think you can generalize it like that.

Comment: @FoxMcCloud I'd like to differentiate between expert knowledge and *obscure, expert knowledge*. I reworded it to *arcane knowledge in a non-gaming topic*, because I think that's the more fundamental distinction. If you wouldn't mind, I'd appreciate a specific rebuttal on what about it is you disagree with, and whether you believe the argument doesn't match [our previously achieved consensus][1], or if the site should change its stance on modding as a whole.

Comment: https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1130/are-questions-about-mods-on-topic + https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/562/do-mod-development-questions-belong-here both cover mods and both agree that talking about mods are on-topic. First point: I disagree with having to ask yourself any generic question before asking a question here except for "Is this on-topic?" Second point: I disagree that you can't lump all modding into one generic category as there are tons of things that go into modding. Mods have been used to make games playable which are important and on-topic IMO

Comment: @FoxMcCloud The question in question is not asking about how to use a mod. The part with which I have an issue states: *Is there something I can do such that **my definition** and requirements of faction_succ_feudal_elective takes precedence over the games' definition?* The relevant part being that OP is looking for a solution to make their own "minimod" function correctly. Asking for help in making a custom mod (regardless of size) falls squarely under "modding" IMO. Your linked metas permit questions *about existing* mods, but not about *creating* or *improving* mods.

Comment: @Schism I agree with everything you said and I understand where your issues are with this question. I was originally answering your question as to why I didn't like your answer to this meta question.

Comment: @FoxMcCloud Thanks for sharing your thoughts! :-)